# Returning arbitrary objects from Flask views

Tags: python, flask

According to the Flask documentation for the [Flask.make_response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.make_response) method, the only types allowed to be returned from a view are instances of app.response_class, str, unicode, a wsgi function, or a tuple with a response object already following one of the above.

I'd like to be able to return my own models and queries from a view and having generic code building an adequate response, serializing the object to an accepted format, building collections from queries, applying filtering conditions, etc. Where's the best place to hook that up?

I considered the following possibilities, but can't figure the one correct way to do it.

- Subclassing Response and setting app.response_class
- Subclassing Flask redefining Flask.make_response
- Wrapping app.route into another decorator
- Flask.after_request
- ?

**edit1**: I already have many APIs with the behavior I need implemented in the views, but I'd like to avoid repeating that everywhere.

**edit2**: I'm actually building a Flask-extension with many default practices used in my applications. While a plain decorator would certainly work, I really need a little more magic than that.

Comment: If you are looking at flask extensions, why not study https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ and see how they handle serialisation?

Comment: I already did. Flask-restless automates the creation of views and applies a decorator to all of them. I won't automate views, so that won't work for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The farther up the chain you go (`make_response`, `dispatch_request` + `handle_user_error`, `full_dispatch_request`, `rewrite Flask from scratch`) the more functionality you will have to re-create.

The easiest thing to do in this case is to override `response_class` and do the serialization there - that leaves you with all the magic that Flask does in `make_response`, `full_dispatch_request` etc., but still gives you control over how to respond to exceptions and serialize responses.  It also leaves all of Flask's hooks in place, so consumers of your extension can override behavior where they need to (and they can re-use their existing knowledge of Flask's request / lifecycle)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just create a function `make_response_from_custom_object` and end your views with

```
return make_response_from_custom_object(custom_object)
```

If it is going to be common I would put it into a `@response_from_custom_object` decorator, but hooking into Flask seems an overkill. You can chain decorators, so wrapping `app.route` does not make sense too; all you need is

```
@app.route(..)
@response_from_custom_object
def view(...):
    ...
```

If you can do it the simple and explicit way, there is no sense to make your code do magic and thus be less comprehensible.

Comment: That's certainly a valid solution, but I actually need to do that magic. I'm writing a Flask extension that follows the patterns and practices adopted by my team, so that behavior will be properly documented. We prefer having some magic happening in the background, but things falling in place as we want easily than doing everything by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Python is dyanmic by nature, so while this probably isn't the best practice, you can reassign the `make_response` method on the application to whatever you want.

To avoid having to recreate the default functionality, you can save a reference to the original function and use that to implement your new function.

I used this recently in a project to add the ability to return instances of a custom `Serializable` class directly from flask views.

```py
app = Flask("StarCorp")

__original_make_response = app.make_response


def convert_custom_object(obj):

    # Check if the returned object is "Serializable"
    if not isinstance(obj, Serializable):
        # Nope, do whatever flask normally does
        return __original_make_response(obj)

    # It is, get a `dict` from `obj` using the `json` method
    data = obj.json
    data.pop(TYPE_META)  # Don't share the type meta info of an object with users

    # Let flask turn the `dict` into a `json` response
    return __original_make_response(data)  

app.make_response = convert_custom_object
```

Since flask extensions typically provide an `init_app(app)` method I'm sure you could build an extension that monkey patches the passed in application object in a similar manner.